# How to decompose a rational function into 2 functions?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

Suppose that $h(x) = (f ◦ g)(x)$ and $ \frac{27x^3+3x}{3x-1}$. Solve for $f(x)$ and $g(x)$.

I'm having a hard time decomposing this rational function. I knew a bit about the composition functions. I tried my best to find the functions and I also used trial-error but I can't still find the result. I'm still in basic math specifically functions.

I tried this:
$ 
h(x) = \frac{3x(9x^2+1)}{3x-1}
$ I factored the numerator. I also intend to let $g(x) = 9x^2+1$, but there are still terms in $x$ which I cannot manipulate.

If I also let $g(x) = x$ in given $h(x)$, the function $f(x)$ will equal to $h(x)$ itself. Is this the correct answer? Is there anything else to get the function aside from $func(x) = x$?

What is the best technique to decompose this give rational function into 2 functions?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. You'll get a lot more help if you show that you have made a real effort to solve the problem yourself, even if you haven't made much progress. What are your thoughts? What have you tried? How far could you get? Where are you stuck? This question will likely be closed if you don't add more context. Please respond by editing the question body. Clarifications don't belong in the comments.

Comment: Three of the terms are related to $ \ 3x \ . $ Does that suggest what the other function could be?

Comment: Without further context, it doesn't really make sense to talk of "solving for $f$ and $g$" since almost anything is possible here. The simplest would be to set $f(x)=x$ or $g(x)=x$.

Comment: Thanks for adding some context. Do you see what happens when $f(x)=x$ or $g(x)=x$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might find the question difficult because there's really no right answer; there are (infinitely) many ways to decompose $h$ into two other functions, and there's no such thing as *the* correct answer or the "best technique".

You mention trying
$$h(x) = \frac{3x(9x^2+1)}{3x-1}$$

From here, notice that $9x^2 = (3x)^2$, so let's try
$$f(g(x)) = \frac{3x((3x)^2+1)}{3x-1}$$

Now with this common element of $3x$ in several places, you could let $g(x)=3x$, so that

$$f(g(x)) = \frac{g(x)((g(x))^2+1)}{g(x)-1}$$

In other words, we have
$$f(x) = \frac{x(x^2+1)}{x-1}, \quad g(x)=3x$$

That's one possible answer, but keep in mind that there are a vast number of other answers. For example, consider $g(x) = 10\left(\frac{27x^3+3x}{3x-1}\right)$ and $f(x) = \frac1{10}x$, etc.